# What function is called when android application is closed from the taskbar?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I am making an application which has a form entry and data is being saved using SQLite. The form is like a wizard so it saves each form data in a different table before moving on to the next form. The wizard has to be completed according to my requirement. But when a person closes the app from the task bar then my data is saved incompletely without completing the wizard which produces issues in accessing the form data later on as it does not save all the forms.

I want the incomplete data entered to be deleted when he removes the application from the task bar so that there is no incomplete data left in the application.

When I minimize the application then **onStop()** function is automatically called but I want the delete action to be taken on the SqLite table only if the app is removed from the task bar. So, how can I achieve this?

Any solutions or ideas are welcome.

Comment: I don't think any of the activity lifecycle methods will be called. You are forcefully killing the process. Nothing happens after that.

Comment: So is there a way that I stop the user from closing the application from the task bar?

Comment: use sqlite transactions for that

Comment: No. I don't think there will be a provision for an app not to not get itself killed. In any case, as @pskink suggests, you can use splite transactions. Make the entire form insertion one atomic transaction, and you must be good to go.